How to auto expose imported symbols to window/globalThis via Vite/Rollup
I'm using Vite
In my index.js entrypoint file I have a bunch of imports like:
import { truncate } from './utils';

But these are only visible to other code that is imported in index.js
The truncate function is not visible to code in the HTML page unless I also do:
window.truncate = truncate;
// or
globalThis.truncate = truncate;

I sort of get why this is but it feels cumbersome. I have a whole bunch of functions I want to expose.
Is there any way to configure Vite/Rollup to automatically expose imported symbols to the global object? Or some other way to achieve this?
Update
For now I have done:
import * as utils from './utils';
globalThis.utils = utils;

...and it's good enough.
Still interested in alternatives.
